# Ondragstart event not being handled after element is created programmatically

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, svelte, addeventlistener, sveltekit

Im creating a web builder, Im using svelte to facilitate some of the functionality of the UI but the web builder itself is almost pure javascript. I created a tool panel in whith diferent dragable elements that are created proramatically so that they can be droped on the canvas (its a div but i call it canvas for structual purposes). However to create the html elements in the canvas I was thinking of passing the tag name as a text and have it create a new element of that type inside the canvas.

The drop is working and the elements are in deed dragable however the issue is with the ondragstart property. I've also tried adding an event listener to the element and this still doesnt work. There are three main components in this operation. 1st the tool panel which is the following. This is where the user will see his tools and be able to drag them into the canvas

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import {define_default_styles, define_default_content} from "$lib/helpers/default_element_configurations";

    let hidden:boolean = true
    let element_declaration:string[] = ["div", "h1", "h2", "p", "form", "input", "button"]
    let elements: (string | undefined)[] = [];
    let element_panel:HTMLElement

    onMount(()=>{
        for(let element of element_declaration){ 
            let newElement = document.createElement(element)
            newElement.className="rounded p-2 border"
            newElement.draggable=true
            newElement.ondragstart=(event)=>{
                console.log("dragstart event fired");
                event.dataTransfer?.setData("text/plain", "div");
                console.log("Data set: ", event.dataTransfer?.getData("text/plain"));
            }
            define_default_styles(newElement,element)
            define_default_content(newElement,element)
            elements.push(newElement.outerHTML)
        }
    })

</script>


<div class="flex items-center space-x-2 p-2 bg-gray-200">
    <h1 class="text-blue-500 font-bold text-xl">Scripter Web-Builder</h1>
    <button on:click={()=>{hidden=false}} class="bg-blue-500 text-white rounded text-center px-2 text-xl font-bold py-1 hover:bg-blue-700 active:bg-blue-900">+</button>
    
</div>
{#if !hidden}
    <div bind:this={element_panel} class="absolute border-2 w-1/4 min-h-52 bg-gray-50 rounded shadow-md">
        {#each elements as element}
            <div class="p-2">{@html element}</div>
        {/each}
    </div>
{/if}
```

This is a helper function that adds aditional functionality, this is where i tried to add the event listener. I already deleted the event listenr in the code but ill add it again for ilustrative porpuses
`

```
export function define_default_content(node:HTMLElement, node_type:string){
    switch(node_type){
        case "div":
            node.innerText="div"
            node.addEventListener("dragstart" ,(event)=>{
                console.log("dragstart event fired");
                event.dataTransfer?.setData("text/plain", "div");
                console.log("Data set: ", event.dataTransfer?.getData("text/plain"));
            })
            node.addEventListener("drop", (event)=>{event.stopPropagation()})
        break;
```

finally this is the canvas which does work as advertised

```
<script lang="ts">
    import {onMount} from "svelte"

    let canvas:HTMLElement
    onMount(()=>{
        canvas.addEventListener("dragenter",(e)=>e.preventDefault())
        canvas.addEventListener("dragover",(e)=>e.preventDefault())
        canvas.addEventListener("drop",(e)=>console.log(e.dataTransfer?.getData("text/plain")))
    })    
</script>


<div bind:this={canvas}>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? Just use `{#each}` and `<svelte:element>`.

Comment: Because its a web builder, the objective is to have and html output you can use in the end. So you can edit a front end in a way similar to canva. Where you can edit and resize the content at will

Comment: Svelte just outputs HTML, you are only making it harder by not using it and instead falling back to manual DOM manipulation.

Comment: Thats not the purpose of the application. The dom manipulation has to be done programmatically in order to allow better communication between components. I already have read the whole svelte documentation and it doesn't support the features I need

Comment: I do not see anything here that would not be supported.

Comment: Aditionally the issue is not the the dom manipulations, those already work as expected the thing that isn't working as expected is the addition of the event listeners which must be created proramatically for scalability reasons

Comment: Its designed this way too because the otherwise i would have to create a component for every single html element available instead of doing it once and adding minor modifications

Comment: I also do not see any reason to create components; as noted in my very first comment, you can just use `<svelte:element>`.

Comment: Why are you focusing so much on something that isn't the issue? That works as expected and I know why I'm doing it that way. The reason is because if not I would have to create a component for ever singe html element in existence instead of adding it as a string to an array

Comment: You don't have to do that, have you even looked at [the docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#svelte-element)? The reason why I am pointing this out is, that you are clearly not using Svelte as intended and chances are that the problems you have, are *only* there because you insist on direct DOM manipulation.

Comment: As I stated in the first sentences of the post, the objective is not to build a svelte application this is a javascript application with some svelte to facilitate development

Comment: Take a look at plasmic, im building an app like that one

Comment: The docs you are refering to are limited. They will not work for user generated elements that are rendered into the display

Comment: Oh wait nvm I see what you mean now, I think I found a way around the issue by using that. Thanks

Comment: Hey man, I hadn't understood you earlier. I unfortunately wasn't on my computer, but once I was able to read it properly I saw you were correct. Thanks for the help, and sorry for the incontinence. You can write it as the answer, and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to avoid manual DOM manipulation, among other things this can cause interference with mounting/unmounting of components.

For something like this, arbitrary elements can be added via `{#each}` and [`<svelte:element>`](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#svelte-element).